# Add events and follow-up time to tbl_uvregression

Tags: r, gtsummary

I've recently starting using the {gtsummary} package for tabulating regression outputs and have found it really helpful!

One issue I've run into relates to the presentation of survival analysis data.

I would like to include the number of events and the length of follow-up time per level of each categorical variable.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  time = sample(1:1000, 100, replace = TRUE),
  event = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
  gender = sample(c("M", "F"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

tbl_uvregression(
  df, 
  method = survival::coxph, 
  y = survival::Surv(time = time, 
                     event = event)
)
```

By default the output includes a column `N` which refers to the number of subjects included in the model for each variable. I would like this and the follow-up time split and presented for each level of the categorical varialbe `gender`.

Can this be done using the {gtsummary} package, or would I need to calculate this separately and somehow merge it to the table?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's planned to update `add_n()` and `add_nevent()` to include an argument to optionally add the Ns directly to the levels for categorical variables.

In the meantime, you can build `tbl_summary()` tables with these counts, and merge them with the Cox model results.  Example below, and there is a similar example in the table gallery on the gtsummary website (http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gallery.html#regression-tables-1).

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  time = sample(1:1000, 100, replace = TRUE),
  event = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
  gender = sample(c("M", "F"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# calculate the total N by gender
tbl_n <- df %>% select(gender) %>% 
  tbl_summary(statistic = everything() ~ "{n}") %>%
  modify_header(stat_0 ~ "**N**") %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA)

# calculate the event N by gender
tbl_nevent <- df %>% filter(event == 1) %>% select(gender) %>% 
  tbl_summary(statistic = everything() ~ "{n}") %>%
  modify_header(stat_0 ~ "**Event N**")  %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA)

# build cox models
tbl_cox <-
  tbl_uvregression(
  df, 
  method = survival::coxph, 
  y = survival::Surv(time = time, event = event),
  exponentiate = TRUE,
  hide_n = TRUE
)

# merge tbls together
tbl_merge(list(tbl_n, tbl_nevent, tbl_cox)) %>%
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA)
```

[image]

I haven't thought about a way to add followup time to these tables. But I'll think on the best implementation. It would like be via the `tbl_survfit()` family of functions that @Mike mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel - this certainly moves me in the right direction. Apologies for not looking more carefully at your documentation - that's of course always the first lesson!

Comment: For the follow-up time, it's straightforward to calculate the time per level using dplyr with the output being a dataframe. Is it possible to convert this to a gtsummary object directly from a dataframe, then merge with the other tbls? I know that gt::gt() will convert a data frame to a gt object, but can't find a way to merge gt objects unfortunately.

Comment: There are two ways you could go about this. 1. Convert the  gtsummary object to a tibble with `as_tibble(tbl_cox)`, and merge in the calculated follow-up time. 2. In the gtsummary object, the table being printed is `tbl_cox$table_body`. You can merge your estimates there as well.

Comment: That's great Daniel - I don't know why I didn't examine the gtsummary object more closely. A good lesson. Thanks for the great (and quick) answers!

Answer (score 1):

So this is an open issue with `gtsummary` on github. One solution using `gtsummary` that gives some number of events:

```
tbl_survfit(survfit(Surv(time, event) ~gender, df), times = c(50,100)) %>% 
  add_nevent() %>% 
  add_n()
```

Comment: These functions were released earlier this month, FYI

Comment: Thanks @Mike - I had seen these functions and was expecting them to calculate events for each level of a variable since that's one component of what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, they don't yet do that, but good to know that the issue has been posted to GH.